# how to create breaks in custom log file in cakephp 3

Tags: logging, line-breaks

[I want to breaks line after each info,error etc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8ZE3.png)

Comment: Please go through this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to know how to ask a question on stackoverflow.

Comment: Please help me... what is problem in my question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my question answer. If we want to line break in custom log file please use "PHP_EOL"

Log::Info('Dashboard successfully running.'.PHP_EOL, 'custom_log');